# Create a context menu item: Take Ownership of files/folders

Tags: nautilus, context-menu

I want this command:

```
sudo chown $USER -R ./
```

To appear in my **Nautilus** context menu, so that I can quickly take ownership of files.

Is this possible, since this is a sudo command? If so, how?

Comment: For the `sudo` part, you could use `gksudo` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Your (short) script seems not to do the job as a nautilus script, but [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=683945) on Ubuntuforums, I found one that works quite nicely. It has some more advanced options, as described in the poster's comment on Ubuntuforums:

*"Note: This is non-recursive by default, so it will only operate on the specific folder and files that you have selected. If you want recursive behavior - uncomment the "#RECURSIVE=-R;" line. It is left out be default since the risk of messing up ownerships is pretty big when something like this gets so easy.* "

**How to use**

The script below is copied without a change. Paste it in an empty file and save it in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` (the script's comment mentions `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`, but that seems outdated) , make it executable, and after log out / in, it will be available in the context menu (under `> scripts`).

**Note**: you need gksu to be installed to use it

```
#!/bin/bash
#Title=Make owned by current user
#Title[se]=Gör nuvarande användare till ägare

# Make owned by current user - Makes the selected files owned by the current user with group 
# being the user's primary group (the first in the output from the "groups" command)

# Installation:
# Put this script into the Nautilus script dir (~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts) and make it executable.
#
# Usage:
# Right-click on files in Nautilus and choose Scripts -> Make owned by current user
#
# Notes:
# This operates non-recursively by default, so it will only operate on the specific folder and files that 
# you have selected. If you want recursive behavior - uncomment the "#RECURSIVE=-R;" line further down.
# It is left out be default since the risk of messing up ownerships is pretty big when something 
# like this gets so easy. 
#
# Acknowledements and version history:
# v20080131 - Fredrik Wollsén
#
# License GPL v3
#
# Feel free to provide feedback on this script here:
# http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=683945
#
# Suggestions for improvements:
#  - Show a zenity dialogue box to dynamically decide whether or not the command 
#    should be run recursively or not.
#  - Show a zenity progress bar for the execution of the command.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE AUTHOR ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
# ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY
# DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
# DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
# GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS
# INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER
# IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR
# OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN
# IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

USER=`whoami`;
GROUP=`groups | sed -r 's/ .*//g'`;
#RECURSIVE=-R; # Uncomment this to make the ownerships be implemented resursively

# default to a group name identical to the username if a group is not found (is this case even possible? this if-statement could be totally useless - but: better safe than sorry...)
if [ "$GROUP" == "" ] ; then
GROUP=$USER;
fi

gksudo -- chown -v $RECURSIVE $USER:$GROUP "$@"| zenity --text-info --height=100 --width=300;

exit 0;
```